# Codeigniter Force download works in WAMP but not works in real server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I want to make a direct link of a .jpg image using codeigniter.

Here is my code sample.

```
function download_menu() {
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $fileName = "foodmenu.jpg";
        $file = realpath("images") . "\\" . $fileName;
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            $data = file_get_contents($file);
            force_download($fileName, $data);
        } else {
            redirect(base_url());
        }
    }
```

The following code works fine in WAMP Server but in real server it redirects the link to base_url. according to code it means in real server does not finds the file, hence images folder and foodmenu.jpg exists.

Any help ????

Answer (score 1):

It seems not getting the path on server

```
 $file =   file_get_contents(base_url()."images/folder/if/any/$fileName");
 if (file_exists($file)) {           
        force_download($fileName, $file);
    } else {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
```

Comment: This also didn't work... I taught the file already exist why should I check for existence, I get rid of if and else blocks and directly called force download the file. it worked.